# foreachPartitionAsync throws cannot call methods on stopped SparkContext

Tags: scala, asynchronous, apache-spark, future

I have 2 files with different data. I am trying to read them in 2 diff RDDs & then convert them to Dataframe & insert into hive. I was able to do this normal code.But spark processed one RDD computation after another . So 2nd one was waiting for the 1st to get over though I have enough resources in the cluster. I I learned that RDDs computation can be parallelized using Async methods. So I am trying foreachPartitionAsync. But it throws error which I am not able to debug further. Sample code:

```
object asynccode {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Parser")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
    import hiveContext.implicits._

    val ercs = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://x.x.x.x:8020/file1.txt")
    val test = ercs.map { k =>
      var rc = method1(k._2, k._1).toSeq
      rc
    }
      .flatMap(identity)
      .foreachPartitionAsync { f =>
        f.toSeq.toDF()
          .write.insertInto("dbname.tablename1")
      }

    val ercs2 = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://x.x.x.x:8020/file2.txt")
    val test2 = ercs2.map { k =>
      var rs = method2(k._2, k._1)
      rs
    }
      .flatMap(identity)
      .foreachPartitionAsync(f => f.toSeq.toDF()
        .write.insertInto("dbname.tablename2")

      )
    sc.stop()
  }

  def method1 = ???
  def method2 = ???
}
```

But it throws Below error message. If I remove foreachPartitionAsync from the code, it works fine. Not Sure what I do wrong regarding foreachPartitionAsync.

> Task serialization failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.

UPDATE : 
Thanks for your suggestion. I updated it like below. But now its not doing anything at all. Spark web UI , I can see no stage is being triggered(its empty). None of my tables are updated as well. But job is completed with no error.

```
val ercs = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://x.x.x.x:8020/file1.txt")
    val test = ercs.map { k =>
      var rc = method1(k._2, k._1).toSeq
      rc
    }
      .flatMap(identity)
     toDF()
     val f1 = Future(test.write.insertInto("dbname.tablename1"))
      }

    val ercs2 = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://x.x.x.x:8020/file2.txt")
    val test2 = ercs2.map { k =>
      var rs = method2(k._2, k._1)
      rs
    }
      .flatMap(identity)
      toSeq.toDF()

val f2 = Future(test2.write.insertInto("dbname.tablename2"))

      )
      Future.sequence(Seq(f1,f2)).onComplete(_ => sc.stop)
```

Is anything I did miss?

Answer (score 1):

You stop `SparkContext` without waiting for `FutureActions` to complete. You should wait for actions to complete and stop context in response:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}

val f1: Future[Unit] = sc.range(1, 200).foreachAsync(_ => Thread.sleep(10))
val f2: Future[Unit] = sc.range(1, 200).foreachAsync(_ => Thread.sleep(10))

Future.sequence(Seq(f1, f2)).onComplete {
  case Success(_) => sc.stop
  case Failure(e) => 
    e.printStackTrace  // or some other appropriate actions 
    sc.stop
}
```

That being said your code is invalid even if we ignore async actions. You **cannot use distributed data structures inside an action or a transformation**:

```
 .foreachPartitionAsync(
   f => f.toSeq.toDF().write.insertInto("dbname.tablename2")
 )
```

If you want asynchronous write actions use `Futures` directly:

```
val df1: Dataframe = ???
val df2: Dataframe = ???

val f1: Future[Unit] = Future(df1.write.insertInto("dbname.tablename1"))
val f2: Future[Unit] = Future(df2.write.insertInto("dbname.tablename2"))
```

and wait for actions to complete as shown above.